VS Code terminal runs Python code as different user
When running this file with python test.py:
import os
import getpass

print(f"Env thinks the user is {os.getlogin()}")
print(f"Effective user is {getpass.getuser()}")

in my VS Code terminal I get:
Env thinks the user is root
Effective user is johndoe

but running it in a normal macOS terminal gives
Env thinks the user is johndoe
Effective user is johndoe

Does anyone know why there is a difference? Unfortunately this causes a permission errors when not using my user. Is it a setting in VS Code is misconfigured etc.?

When VS Code is launched from the macOS Dock or Launchpad,
it's not associated with a login shell, so os.getlogin() returns root.
However, when you open a terminal outside of VS Code, it's associated with a login shell, so os.getlogin() returns your username.
If you try launching VS Code from the terminal using the code command, it should associate VS Code with a login shell, causing os.getlogin() to return your username.
